# Way to override the way html tags are generated by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to override particular tag generations with VS2010?

Right now when you type `<table>`, VS will create the matching `</table>` tag to close the statement. When I type `<table>`, I'd like VS to generate `<tr><td></td></tr></table>`.

I'm pretty sure I could do this with a Macro, but it would be nice to be able to type normally and have this generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a code snippet and then toggle that...

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/16/html-code-snippets-vstipedit0018.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150624031920/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/16/html-code-snippets-vstipedit0018.aspx)

Comment: Not what I was hoping for but does do the trick. I was able to edit the default table snippet (which puts in extra tags like cellspacing="0"). Now I just have to remember to use it :)